# When did "Delta" start being used for "effectiveness" or "complexity" measure in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, etymology, meaning-in-context

I came across [this article](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/local/2015/05/17/arkansaw-ar-kansas/27489055/) looking to resolve the dilemma of pronunciation of "Arkansas", and found a strange use of word "Delta" that is rare.

If in that article you see this sentence "Susy, I hope .... as clear as Delta mud.". Now I know that "as clear as mud" is a rhetoric that means "difficult to understand", but there's a very rare use of word "Delta" for effect, which hints at "real mud" or "weird(like a maze, really complex) mud", also as in "really muddy" or "very muddy".

So my question, when did "Delta" start to be used for "effectiveness" and/or "complexity" measure for the adjective coming after it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So my question, when did "Delta" start to be used for "effectiveness" and/or "complexity" measure for the adjective coming after it?

*Delta* has never meant what you purport it to mean. You have misunderstood the sentence altogether, particularly the proper noun *Delta* used attributively here.
Per the [eponymous Wikipedia article on said *Delta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mississippi_Delta):

> The **Mississippi Delta**, also known as the **Yazoo–Mississippi Delta**, or simply **the Delta**, is the distinctive northwest section of the U.S. state of Mississippi (and portions of Arkansas and Louisiana) that lies between the Mississippi and Yazoo Rivers. The region has been called "The Most Southern Place on Earth"[¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mississippi_Delta#cite_note-1) ("Southern" in the sense of "characteristic of its region, the American South"), because of its unique racial, cultural, and economic history.

There's even a website named [*Visit the Delta*](https://www.visitthedelta.com/) that's all about it.

In comments Laurel pointed out that given our Arkansan context here, its *Delta* is rather more likely to refer to the adjacent [Arkansas Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkansas_Delta):

> The **Arkansas Delta** is one of the six natural regions of the state of Arkansas. Willard B. Gatewood Jr., author of *The Arkansas Delta: Land of Paradox*, says that rich cotton lands of the Arkansas Delta make that area "The Deepest of the Deep South."[¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkansas_Delta#cite_note-1) [...] While the Arkansas Delta shares many geographic similarities with the Mississippi Delta, it is distinguished by its five unique sub-regions: [...]

There is no adjective following the noun *Delta*: the word following it is the noun *mud*. The mud of the Delta is not clear. All mud is unclear. The Delta mud was just the nearest mud to kick up as an example.

Comment: The Wikipedia article you're looking for is [Arkansas Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkansas_Delta) :p

Comment: @Laurel (*wipes eyes*) Where the one delta stops and the other one starts is ... muddy.

Comment: “It’s a treat to beat your feet on the Mississippi mud.”